# How can I insert p tags into existing divs/HTML

Tags: php, web-scraping

I scraped html data from web sites using simplehtmldom_1_5 and after scraped I want to insert every text in a `<p>` tag with different id of every `<p>` tag as a explained below:

```
 Suppose scrapped data:

          <div class="maincontainer">
            <div class="first">
            first text 
            </div>
            <div class="second">
            second text 
            </div>

            <div class="third">
            third text 
            </div>

            <div class="fourth">
            fourth text 
            </div>
fifth string 
          </div>

    And I want result like this below:

          <div class="maincontainer">
            <div class="first">
            <p  id="1">first text </p> 
            </div>
            <div class="second">
            <p  id="2">second text </p>
            </div>

            <div class="third">
            <p  id="3">third text </p>
            </div>

            <div class="fourth">
            <p  id="4">fourth text </p>
            </div>
    <p  id="5">   fifth string </p>
          </div>
```

Guys I want to do this during scraping not after scraping.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: Regular Expressions may work, but parsing HTML is not the best thing to do ;-)

Comment: @akluth — The question mentions simplehtmldom. Let's not go near regex for this.

Comment: Aww snap, didn't saw that, thanks for metioning. Forget the Regex thing @ OP, but my first question should still be valid: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: i succesfully done this using simplehtmldom_1_5:<div class="item" id="1111">
<div class="item" id="1112">
first text
</div>
<div class="item" id="1113">
second text 
</div>

<div class="item" id="1114">
third text 
</div>

<div class="item" id="1115">
fourth text 
</div>
</div>

Comment: but i stuck to add every text in p tags with different id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').each(function (i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.find('div, span, div, img, ul, a').length) {
            var elData = $this.html();
            if ($.trim(elData) != '') {
                var appendData = '<p  id="' + (i + 1) + '">' + elData + '</p>';
                $this.html(appendData);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

@ [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/AejLc/3/)

Comment: Neeraj i appreciate your answer but formatting of texts and divs are not always same because i am scraping data from different sites using simplehtmldom. ok if data is like in this format then <div class="not same">
<div class="first">
first text 
</div>
<div class="asdda">
 <img src="anc.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="second">
 <div class="abc">
<img src="anc.jpg" />
 abc text
 <div class="input">
 <input type="text" value="sumit"  />
 input text
 </div>
second text 
</div>

<div class="third">
third text 
</div>

<div class="fourth">
fourth text 
</div>
fiifth text outside
</div>

Comment: and text means any string .

Comment: thanks again neeraj check on this link http://jsfiddle.net/sharma9853/GBe6p/ i added all new id's and classes using simplehtmldom in div tags if you can help me using simplehtmldom then it will be more appreciative. i tried your jquery code in this it not works for me it erase all my html data.

Comment: i need my whole data in my same format i just need to add every text in p tags with new id's.

Comment: Okay, Sumit.. Let me do something with your code tomorrow in office :). I'll let you know solution..

Comment: Hi Sumit.. Now check this http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/AejLc/3/. it's working as you want..

Comment: I am glad that I could help you... Mr. Sumit

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the most efficent way to do so
Working jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Diabl0570/FhZZQ/1/

```
//jquery
$(function(){
    var count = 1;
    $("div.maincontainer div").each(function(){
           var html = $(this).html(); 
        $(this).html("<span id='"+count+"'>"+ html + "</span>");
        count= count+1;
    });
});
```

Comment: friend may be you are right with your jquery code but i want to do this at the time when i scraped data with simplehtmldom_1_5

Answer (score 0):

Using perl, You could try bellow code. I called the input file as "xml.xml". I suppose something similar works in php, doesn't it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<xml.xml" or die;
my $i;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/\s*</||/^\s*$/) { print; next }
    ++$i;
    s{^(\s*)(.*)$}{$1<p id="$i">$2</p>};
    redo;
}
close $fh;
```